# Methods to procedurally generate objects and enemies in an open world

Tags: 2d, godot, procedural-generation

I've been working on my first game recently and have gotten to the part where I need to consider how I handle creating my game world and configuring how levels are even created. I've been thinking of ways I could go about this, but I'd like some ideas and maybe some example tutorials on how others have done similar things for Godot 4.0 in 2D.

The game I'm working on is basically aiming to be similar to Barotrauma and FasterThanLight combined, but on a smaller scope since I'm generally new to programming games. My current idea for world generation is to create an invisible grid or chunks that will have a chance to spawn X object or Y enemy, and that chunk gets marked as having spawned that enemy and parsing parameters to affect the likelihood of another object or enemy spawning adjacent to that chunk. E.G Asteroid spawns in chunk -> Adajcent chunks are more likely to spawn with smaller asteroids.Is this a good method to go about this?

The problem with this is that I don't really know how to create a system like this in code, and I don't want to invest a lot of time and backtrack/scrap it for another method down the line since I don't have to much free time to program, so if anyone knows any tutorials or examples or something lmk!

Besides that though, do you have any ideas as to other methods to achieve similar effects? Are there other simpler ways besides hand-crafting large levels?

Game looks like this
[image: Vidya game]

Comment: Is there a reason why you think your idea won't work or is not ideal? Or is there something preventing you from implementing it?

Comment: I'm more asking if there are other alternative methods that may be more appropriate, since I'm new to game development and especially creating procedural generated systems. So if there are methods I don't know of or you think are better, I'd appreciate if you let me know. Right now I'm looking into using Cellular Automata with Noise. Not sure if this is appropriate for a game of this type, but I'll be experimenting.

Comment: Wave function collapse is the only other thing that comes to mind, but I'm not convinced it is a good solution for your use case. Try searching in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com there is plenty on procedural generation, you might find something useful.